Will joining two pieces with UV resin provide a strong bond?
I have this 3D model:

The original piece is a 1-part piece.
But it's very difficult to print it without supports.
I want to avoid using supports, so I can maintain quality in the print.
I think in cutting in two pieces and then joining them.
I see that some people use the resin as a glue to join both parts.
Something like this:



This piece has to be strong due to it being subjected to big mechanical stress
Is this method good in this case? Could the piece lose some resistance in the union?

I don't have a resin printer, but would the color of the resin matter? If not tranparent, how would the resin harden in the joint? The video is unclear at the end because of the layover.

Video is clear to explain how to join two pieces using some PCB coating resin but you need to test how strong is the bonding, If you are unsing a resin printer I recommend to use the same resin to join the parts. if you are using PLA, ABS or another other material you may need to use diferent glue; mechanical stress may get the parts away, there are glue for torsion, shock stress, peel off, covering, slip, etc. PCB coating is not such strong.
